# How to store an image in pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, conv-neural-network, array-broadcasting

I have the following line of code.

```
v = chemcepterize_mol(mol, embed=10, res=0.2)
```

The function `chemcepterize_mol` takes some arguments like `mol, embed, res`.
This function `chemcepterize_mol` return a value which i store in `v` which is an ordinary variable.

This `v` is actually a vector representing three dimensional image.

The shape of the `v`  is as follows.

```
print(v.shape) 
(100, 100, 4)
```

100X100 pixels image with 4 channels.

When I show this image, It looks like below.

```
plt.imshow(v[:,:,:3])
```

[image: 100x100x4 image]

Up to this point, it works fine. But I have few of these types of images (3 dimensional vectors) which I need to store in my dataframe. That means, I need to call this function `chemcepterize_mol`  few times, lets say 10 times to obtain 10 images.

For that I wrote a for loop like this below.

```
v = np.ndarray(shape=(100,100, 4,1))
for x in range(10):

   v[x]=chemcepterize_mol(data["mol"][x],embed=10,res=0.2)
```

Here, `data["mol"][x]`is the `x` entry of the column `mol` in my data frame `data`. For each of these `data["mol"][x]` values , the `chemcepterize_mol` will give me a different 3 dimensional vector which I need to store.

I declared  `v = np.ndarray(shape=(100,100, 4,1))` so that in it's last dimension, I can store all my vectors (images), but it it given me this error.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,100,4) into shape (100,4,1)
```

How can I store all my vectors in some array or preferably in separate pandas data frame column.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to wrap the images in a python list. That makes it possible to store it in a pandas DataFrame.

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['img'] = [img] # Wrap image in python list

# Add another row using the "dictionary way"
d2 = {'img': [img2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d2)
df.append(df2)
```